# PHP form validation failure

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to do form field validation with php. I am checking if the submit button isset first and then if the form fields are empty, save it in a error variable, else if its not empty I have a function doing som form cleanup and setting the value to the textfield.Then submitted to another page.

But my error handling never happens and the form with empty fields are submitted to my action page url.

Whats wrong with code:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
 $fnameErr = "";
 $lnameErr = "";
 $Fname = "";
 $Lname = "";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

if (empty($_POST["FirstName"])) {
$fnameErr = "First name is required";
} else {
$Fname = form_input($_POST["FirstName"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["LastName"])) {
$lnameErr = "Last name is required";
} else {
$Lname = form_input($_POST["LastName"]);
}

 }

function form_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
 ?>
 <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
  <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form action="intro.html.php" method="POST">
        Förnamn: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
        <br>
        Efternamn: <input type="text" name="LastName">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing stopping this page from proceeding to the end, regardless of input. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

if file of action form is different with the form file you need to check the input on action.

here the index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<?php
    /* get the return value when is not valid on into.html.php*/
    $fname = $_GET['fName']; $lname = $_GET['lName'];
    if($_GET['fName']=='false'){
        $fnameErr = "First name is required"; /*set value to show  notif*/
        $fname ="";
    }
    if($_GET['lName']=='false'){
        $lnameErr = "First name is required"; /*set value to show  notif*/
        $lname    ="";
    }
?>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <form action="intro.html.php" method="POST">
        Förnamn: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"> 
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
        <br>
        Efternamn: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $lname;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then set your intro.html.php like this

```
<?php
function form_input($data) {
    if($data!=""){ /*add condition if data != "" then run so we don't need more else on section if $_POST is empty*/
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    }
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { /*check the submit*/

    $Fname = form_input($_POST["FirstName"]); /* get post data from input val to variable $Fname*/
    $Lname = form_input($_POST["LastName"]); /* get post data from input val to variable $Lname*/

    if(!empty($_POST["FirstName"]) and !empty($_POST["LastName"])!=""){ /*cek if FirstName and LasName is not empty*/
        /* do what you want to do here*/
        echo ' FName : '.$Fname.' | LName : '.$Lname;
    }
    else{
        /*we will redirect to index.php using javascript*/
        echo '
            <script>
            alert("all input must be field!");
            window.location.href="index.php?fName='.($_POST["FirstName"]==""?'false':$Fname).'&lName='.($_POST["LastName"]==""?'false':$Lname).'"; /* this ridect to index.php and set variable  $_GET fName and variable lName */
            </script>
        ';
    }

}
else{
    echo 'submit is undefined!'; /*echo submit empty, */
}

?>
```

if you want to check input before submit, you can use HTML `<input>` required Attribute [here the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

or you can use jquery to proses ajax submit or just check the input value you can see more in [here](http://api.jquery.com/)

hope this help.

Comment: Really strange, when I run this code both on localhost and live, it does not validate for any empty strings but forwards the page to the action url.

Could you try this on the following url http://www.icloudis.com/php_intro

Comment: are the form and action on same file or different? if in different file,  can u post the source code of intro.html.php?  because i see form action redirect to "intro.html.php"

Comment: the form action is set to a different file. The form itself is a file called index.php and file action is set to intro.html.php and the source code for that file is:

<?php 

echo "Välkommen ".$_POST['FirstName']." ".$_POST['LastName'];

?>

Comment: you need to put validation code into intro.html.php and rediect user back to index.php when the condition you want not reached. i will try update my answer, hope can help

Comment: Thanks, that would be of great help :)

Comment: so the code you pasted in above would workout or were going to update it?

Comment: i already update my code on my answer above, you can try it. you can paste code index.php of my answer to your index.php and code on  intro.html.php of my answer into your  intro.html.php. you can see on intro.html.php comment  /*do what you want to do here*/ you can paste  code you want to do if input not empty after the comment /*do what you want to do here*/.